# How can I construct a sequence of injections $\langle f_\alpha\colon\alpha\to\omega\mid\alpha<\omega_1\rangle$ with a particular coherence property?

Tags: set-theory

> Assuming the axiom of choice, show that there exists a sequence of function $\langle f_\alpha\mid\alpha<\omega_1\rangle$ such that: (1) each $f_\alpha:\alpha\rightarrow\omega$ is injective and (2) for all $\alpha<\beta$, the set $\{\gamma<\alpha\mid f_\alpha(\gamma)\not=f_\beta(\gamma)\}$ is finite.

My knee-jerk reaction in trying to solve this problem is to define the sequence by recursion. But I don't see how to actually carry out the construction (in particular, I don't see how I could ensure that (2) remains to be the case once I pass $\omega$). Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the axiom of choice to prove there exists a sequence $\langle A_\alpha\subseteq\omega\mid\alpha<\omega_1\rangle$ such that for $\alpha<\beta$, $A_\alpha\setminus A_\beta$ is finite.

The idea is to show that every countable sequence with this property can be extended, and using transfinite recursion, we can find such a sequence of length $\omega_1$.

Now proceed by induction to construct your sequence of bijections, where $f_\alpha\colon A_\alpha\to\alpha$ (then the inverses are as wanted), and if $\alpha<\beta$, then $f_\beta$ may disagree with $f_\alpha$ only on values from $A_\alpha\setminus A_\beta$.

Comment: I don't really see what is going on here. The usual construction keeps ranges of $f_{\alpha}$ coinfinite. The main work is at the limit stages,